# r call column by name data.frame return data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I know how to call a data.frame by column name but it returns a numeric vector rather than a data.frame. How to I force it to return a data.frame instead?

```
data = data.frame(rand1 = rnorm(5, sd = 0.3),rand2 = rnorm(5, sd = 0.3) )

data[,'rand2']

[1]  0.54355118 -0.34235808  0.30914102 -0.06509097  0.29061738

class(data[,'rand2'])

[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Take the comma out.  A data frame is a list, so you can do `data["rand2"]` and keep the data.frame class

Answer (score 0):

From you example you can simply use

```
data = data.frame(rand1 = rnorm(5, sd = 0.3),rand2 = rnorm(5, sd = 0.3) )

data[,'rand2',drop=F]

     rand2
1 -0.07895436
2  0.55478780
3 -0.47263459
4  0.17346880
5  0.47885452

class(data[,'rand2',drop=F])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Some other good ideas for data.frames can be found [here](http://blog.datacamp.com/15-easy-solutions-data-frame-problems-r/)